# Trouble with $('this').children not working in my function

Tags: jquery, function, toggle, this, children

So basically I have several links that need to show sliding panels. My initial code is something like this.

```
function view(panel){
$(panel).slideToggle();
};

$('#link1').click(function(){
view('#panel1');
});
```

So the problem I have now is that next to the links I want to include an arrow pointing up when the link is clicked and the panel slides down and have it hide when it's clicked and the panel slides up to indicate that clicking the link again will hide the panel. The arrow is given class="arrow" and is a direct child of the link.

```
function view(panel){
$(panel).slideToggle();
};

$('#link1').click(function(){
view('#panel1');
$(this).children('.arrow').toggle();
});
```

This works, but I don't want to repeat `$(this).children('.arrow').toggle;` for every link (there will be a lot of them). So I did this.

```
function view(panel){
$(panel).slideToggle();
$(this).children('.arrow').toggle();
};

$('#link1').click(function(){
view('#panel1');
});
```

This does nothing and the arrow remains display:none.  Why is that? I don't see how this is interpreted any differently. Can $(this) not be used in a separate function that is called?  I have tried searching but don't know how to search this kind of problem other than.....well typing that question and I don't get any helpful results. Can someone tell me how to make this work by defining it in a function so I don't have to keep repeating the code for every link?

Comment: Since you're concerned with code repetition (and it's good that you are), you could probably simplify a lot more by doing something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bMe9B/

Comment: Well right now it's organized as <div>Link</div><div>Panel</div>.  I do it this way so I can display link without displaying panel until it's clicked.   For the code you showed wouldn't I have to add a containers like this <div><div>link</div><div>panel</div></div>?  That would be a bit more nesting than I'd like. cause I'd have to do it for everything that has a drop panel.  The whole thing works like and expanding flow chart so clicking option shows more options.  (it's not me that wants this its my employer) at least I talked them out of making each option a new page......

Comment: O also I probably should have used btn instead of link to describe the function of the div.  It's not actually a <a> link.

Comment: In that case, you could give your links a class and do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Kn8bw/. Even if that doesn't work quite right, there will almost certainly be a way to do this that doesn't require you to hard code all of your link and div ids.

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I did some experiment pages with this and I looks like a much better way to do this without using a lot of id tags.  I think this will make it easier to change later if I need to since it's more general.  I'm still learning jquery and this type of dom navigation will be really helpful for future use.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
view.call(this, '#panel1');
```

This will keep the context. Or you can do this:

```
function view(panel, link){
    $(panel).slideToggle();
    $(link).children('.arrow').toggle;
};
$('#link1').click(function(){
    view('#panel1', this);
});
```

You could also try something like this:

```
$('#link1, link2' /* or 'a.link', etc */, function() {
    // assuming the has is the panel #panel1
    //$(this.hash).slideToggle();

    // Or using what you already have
    $('panel' + this.id.match(/\d/)).slideToggle();

    $(this).children('.arrow').toggle;
    // Then do something based on the id?
    return false;
});
```

Comment: O yeah.  Sorry my code does have toggle() but I forgot to type it here.  Thanks for the help.  I was hoping to avoid adding another parameter but it seams I don't have much choice.

Comment: You could alternatively use a class on the links and use a single click event. If you needed something different based on the link, you could do it within that.

Comment: Added another option to the list.

Comment: I actually just tried this and it's not working either.  It doesn't seem to understand that I want the child .arrow of #link1.  From what you have here it looks like it should interpret link to be '#link1' but that doesn't seem to be happening.  I also tried a different name for the parameter but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your markup so I can take a look at what `this` might be referring to?

Comment: Not sure if this is right but http://jsfiddle.net/7n4B7/.  I've never used jfiddle before. The part I'm trying to get working is near the end of the code and it's preceded by // pkgPanel View Coding Start

Comment: O also for the class solution suggested, that caused the arrows to appear on all links with that class. Also I named them link in the sample to make it easier to read but they aren't <a> links just divs.

Comment: I inlined all your javascript and CSS (http://jsfiddle.net/7n4B7/4/), and updated the images to use http://placehold.it. When I switch to the `call` method, everything seems to work. I'm going to try and whittle the code down to what we're concerned with here. Unless you tell me that works for you... You may need a more consistent naming structure that is easy to manipulate in a general way.

Comment: Yeah I agree about the naming part.  I was trying to get this up in a hurry for my employers and I plan on cleaning it up before it's live.  Anyway it does seem to work but if I only do view.call(this, '#LVday1Pkgs'); nothing happens. If I do that and view.call(this, '#LVday1type1'); then the arrow appears for the first link but not the next.  It like view.call(this, '#LVday1type1'); is applying this to $('#LVday1') and not $('#LVday1Link1') which means I'll always have one that doesn't work.

Comment: Actually nvm.  I just made the changes to the whole script and I'm not seeing any problems so I believe this is working. Thanks so much for the help.  Also if you had any suggestions of how to simplify the naming or the script in general I'd appreciate it. Keep in mind that each link will eventually show different information.  I'm just waiting for that from my employer.